# How can I draw red horizontal line in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, colors

How can I draw a horizontal line (hr) in a react component using dynamic color?

Here's what I have so far:

```
render {
    let color = 'red';
    return (
        <div> 
            There is a red HR
           <hr />
        <div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

One way to set up the component:

```
const ColoredLine = ({ color }) => (
    <hr
        style={{
            color: color,
            backgroundColor: color,
            height: 5
        }}
    />
);
```

And then use it with:

```
<ColoredLine color="red" />
```

For a full breakdown on how to style `<hr />`, see http://www.sovavsiti.cz/css/hr.html

Comment: you can add example usage also showing the prop passed

Answer (score 8):

```
<hr  style={{
    color: '#000000',
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    height: .5,
    borderColor : '#000000'
}}/>
```

Only adding the `borderColor`, to change the exact full-color change of `<hr />` tag

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple way to create a horizontal line in your react js app

```
    <div style={{ borderTop: "2px solid #fff ", marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20 }}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Below is the code for a simple Horizontal line styled with CSS.

```css
.separator {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<hr class="separator" />
```

Key points I noticed after working with the `<hr />` tag

1. Passing `color` from styles has no effect on `<hr />`. Use `background-color` to change `hr` color with styles.
2. `background-color` works only if `height` is mentioned
3. `border: none` is recommended as hr comes with a default border of `1px`

### React Component

```
function Separator({ color = "black", height = 1 }) {
  return (
    <hr
      style={{
        backgroundColor: color,
        height: height,
        border: "none"
      }}
    />
  );
}

<Separator color="red" height="10px" />
```

Key points

1. I recommend using external styles over inline styles ( unless it's tailwindcss )
2. You need to default `color` to `black` and `height` to `1`. These are the default `<hr />` styles excluding border and if not defaulted you won't see a horizontal line if one of `color, height` is missing

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr)

[image: Edit sof-answer-hr-line]